# How do I get a transparent page/screen in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, screen, transparency

So, everytime I open a new tab (about:newtab) or just a white screen (about:blank).
It would be better, Firefox displays my desktop instead (or what's 'behind' firefox) to work more efficient.

I thought to try Firefox's Add-On 'Stylish' to solve this problem, but those scripts are only for Windows with Aero support.

So... any other ideas how I get a transparent page/screen in Firefox?

**EDIT** To clear things up: I don't want the whole window transparent!

Comment: Just a note:  For the page to be transparent, the browser has to tell GTK that the window/pane background is transparent AND the page background has to be transparent.  Modifying the default about:blank page to have a background of rgba(0,0,0,0) may not do it since it doesn't inform GTK as well.  I can't think of a "Good" way to force this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with using  compiz. Install the compizconfig settings manager 
by following command in terminal.

> sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager

Go to accessibility enable "opacity,brightness and saturation". Click on this icon. Click on the new button at "Windows specific settings". Click on the + button and enter "Firefox" in the value field. Press add... Use slide to influence transparency. 100=no transparancy - 0=100% transparency.
Now you can see the background through firefox.

Comment: Improve your answer with screenshots and I will upvote it.

Comment: argh... I don't like to work with ccsm. - Is this the only way? Because it doesn't work for me.

Comment: K.K Patel you forgot to say that I must write "Class=Firefox" ... but (I thought this was clear) I DON'T want the whole window transparent!

Comment: Now I can see at least something throught the Firefox... Still looking for a solution to make only the [hacked] background transparent.

Comment: That will make all of firefox transparent, not just the background.